# Why do the lines in this longtable misalign?

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs, tablenotes

I run `latexmk -pdfxe` on this MWE

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\LTpre0pt\LTpost0pt
\LTleft1em\LTright1em
\newlength\tabcolwidth
\newlength\firstcoltext
\newlength\rowheight
\setlength{\footskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\rowheight}{13ex}
\newcolumntype{y}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\centering\large
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth
\settowidth\firstcoltext{longest~}
\setlength\tabcolwidth{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\firstcoltext-\tabcolsep-10pt}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
  % \renewcommand\TPTminimum{\textwidth}
  \begin{TableNotes}
    \item[a] \label{tn:a} foo
    \item[b] \label{tn:b} bar
    % \unskip\strut\par
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{longtable}{%
      @{\extracolsep{\fill}}ry{\tabcolwidth}:y{\tabcolwidth}@{}}
      \caption{Please fill in this table.}\\
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{~}
      & \multicolumn{1}{y{\tabcolwidth}}{A}
      & \multicolumn{1}{y{\tabcolwidth}}{B} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \cmidrule{3-3}
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{\raggedleft\textit{continued \ldots}}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \insertTableNotes\\
    \endlastfoot
    \multicolumn{1}{r:}{foo} & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    longest\tnotex{tn:a} & & \\[\rowheight]\cline{1-3}
    foo & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    bar\tnotex{tn:b} & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    baz & & \\[\rowheight]
  \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

How do I get the lines aligned properly? I know this seems similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269183/42348)

---

*edit:*
Adopting the solution from Herbert's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432141/42348), I now excluded booktabs completely. I tried to use `\Xhline` and `\Xcline` from the `makecell` package, the first of which is defined:

```
\newcommand\Xhline[1]{\noalign{\ifnum0=‘}\fi\arrayrulewidth#1%
\ifx\hline\LT@hline\let\@xhline\LT@@hline\fi
\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
```

But the rules appear thicker than expected because apparently there's another `\hline` included. Try uncommenting the arrayrulewidth line. (Or change to `\multicolumn{1}{X@{}}{A}` which causes the table to overflow.) The problem of the intersecting vertical dashed line is also similar using `\Xhline` to booktabs's `\midrule` (I corrected it from running about 2pt into the head). Finally, I also w'd like the footer to be shown "after" the last row on the page.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a5paper]{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}     % \firsthline \lasthline
\usepackage{makecell}  % \Xhline \Xcline
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{arydshln}  % \firsthdashline \lasthdashline
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newlength\heavyrulewidth
\newlength\lightrulewidth
\newlength\rowheight
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{xltabular}{\hfuzz1pt}
\begin{document}
  \centering\small
  % lengths from booktabs.sty
  \setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.08em}
  \setlength\lightrulewidth{0.05em}
  % \setlength\arrayrulewidth{0pt}   % <-- uncomment
  \setlength\tabcolsep{1em}
  \setlength\rowheight{6ex}
  \LTcapwidth=\textwidth
  \noindent
  \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} r X : X @{}}
    \caption{Please fill in this table.}\\\Xhline{\heavyrulewidth}
    % \rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex}
    & \multicolumn{1}{X}{A}
    & \multicolumn{1}{X}{B}\\[-2pt]\Xhline{\lightrulewidth}
    \endhead
    \Xcline{3-3}{\lightrulewidth}
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{\raggedleft\textit{continued \ldots}}
    \endfoot
    \Xhline{\heavyrulewidth}
    \endlastfoot
    foo & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    bar\footnote{bar} & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    foo & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    test a footnote\footnote{foo} & & \\[\rowheight]\cline{1-3}
    foo & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    foo & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
    foo & & \\[\rowheight]
  \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the first page:

[image: a long table with a few alignment problems]

*edit:* (27/05/2018)

I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/sharethewisdom/4b2365f31dd8f49b7a097598ede971ca) with a table that illustrates the application and the reason for vertical lines. I would like top and bottom `\hlines` to have different thicknesses though.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by properly? which lines do you want to change?

Comment: I want the vertical dashed rule to start flush with `\midrule` and at the same time make use of the booktabs features (rulewidth, `\belowrulesep`, `\aboverulesep`, etc...). (I had included the first multicolumn with `{r:}` just to illustrate that the dashed rules do indeed cross `\midrule`)

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with `booktabs` which inserts some more vertical space before and after the horizontal lines. Use simple `\hlines` and stretch the first line. I used `xltabular` which does nearly the same as `threeparttable`.  Important is only:

```
 \caption{Please fill in this table.}\\\hline
    \rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex} & A & B \\\hline
```

Here is my full example:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\newlength\rowheight
\setlength{\rowheight}{13ex}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\centering\large
\LTcapwidth=\textwidth

\noindent
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} r X : X @{}}
\caption{Please fill in this table.}\\\hline
  \rule[-1.25ex]{0pt}{4ex} & A & B \\\hline
\endhead
\cmidrule{3-3}
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\raggedleft\textit{continued \ldots}}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\multicolumn{1}{@{}r:}{foo} & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
            longest\footnote{foo} & & \\[\rowheight]\cline{1-3}
            foo & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
            bar\footnote{bar} & & \\[\rowheight]\cdashline{2-3}
            baz & & \\[\rowheight]
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your almost acceptable solution, please see my edit